# Table only shows when interacting and not by default

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a table in a view controller that is populated through a dictionary from which information is retrieved via a JSON request. In the `viewDidLoad()` function, I call the function that retrieves the data which is added to `IncompletedDeadlines dictionary:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.IncompleteDeadlines = [String:AnyObject]()
    self.retrieveIncompletedDeadlines()
}
```

Everything works however the table only shows when interacted with. I thought maybe the best way to show the table the moment the view appears is by adding a `tableView.reload` to `viewDidAppear` as so:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But this doesn't fix it. I have attached pictures for clarity of the situation. Picture one shows the view the moment the view appears. Picture 2 only happens **once the table is interacted with i.e. swiped**. So my question is how can I get the table to show immediately? I understand there can be a delay because of the load, but I shouldn't have to interact with it for it to show:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/0bgTB]

When the view is interacted with i.e. swiped:

[image]

The `retrieveIncompletedDeadlines()` function is as so:

```
func retrieveIncompletedDeadlines(){
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "https://www.example.com/scripts/retrieveIncompleteDeadlines.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL)
    let user_id = UserDetails[0]
    request.httpMethod = "POST";
    let postString = "user_id=\(user_id)";
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        var err: NSError?
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = json {
                let checker:String = parseJSON["status"] as! String;

                if(checker == "Success"){
                    let resultValue = parseJSON["deadlines"] as! [String:AnyObject]
                    self.IncompleteDeadlines = resultValue
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            err = error
            print(err!);
        }
    }
    task.resume();
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: can you show `self.retrieveIncompletedDeadlines()` ? is it where you get the json?

Comment: It is and I have added it

Comment: I still Can't see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON will be parsed on the background thread but any update to the UI must be done on the main thread hence you have to do it inside  `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` This [article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/9/4/back-to-the-main-thread-dispatchqueuemain) explains well what is the problem.

Furthermore I would write a completions handler which returns the data once the operation has finished. This is another interesting [article](https://grokswift.com/completion-handlers-in-swift/) about.

`Completion handlers are super convenient when your app is doing something that might take a little while, like making an API call, and you need to do something when that task is done, like updating the UI to show the data.`

```
var incompleteDeadlines  = [String:AnyObject]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //please note your original function has changed 
    self.retrieveIncompletedDeadlines { (result, success) in
        if success {
            // once all the data has been parsed you assigned the result to self.incompleteDeadlines
            self.incompleteDeadlines  =  result
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

func retrieveIncompletedDeadlines(_ completion:@escaping ([String:AnyObject] , _ success: Bool)-> Void){
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "https://www.example.com/scripts/retrieveIncompleteDeadlines.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL)
    let user_id = UserDetails[0]
    request.httpMethod = "POST";
    let postString = "user_id=\(user_id)";
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        var err: NSError?
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = json {
                let checker:String = parseJSON["status"] as! String;
                var resultValue = [String:AnyObject]()
                if(checker == "Success"){
                    resultValue = parseJSON["deadlines"] as! [String:AnyObject]
                }

                    completion(resultValue, true)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            err = error
            print(err!);
        }
    }
    task.resume();
}
}
```

Comment: AH Perfect! It has done the trick, I will accept once the timer is up. Thank you! ;)  + how do you mean about the completion handler returning the data?

Comment: Please see updated answer. I made a but of changes so make sure everything is at the right place.